# Getting error while sending http request via curl

Tags: php, json, curl

I want to send charging request through php which I have sent via postman and it worked, but when I try this with php I m getting error response.

I have tried to send the request using curl and used function to send the request. But, after hitting the php I m getting the response that "invalid request" .

**Here is the code snippet:**

```
<?php


define('TML_CHARGE_URL2', 'http://sandbox-apigw.mytelenor.com.mm/v1/mm/en/customers/products/vas');


$client_id="MDq0MdGtZUGZWfanE8k2fva7GsLvwS0I";
$client_secret="GEzAxTE6YYSfLEAD";
$accessToken="ytSxhvjSUfNEurD5M6SOJPm6XAfu"; 

/* CP & Product Codes */

$cpid="15";
$login="apigwtest";
$password="apigwtestpwd";
$client_id="175612092873562378";
$msisdn="9791000601";

$prod_code = "APIGW_TEST";



$requestParamList = array("cpID" => $cpid,
"clientTransactionId" => $client_id,
"loginName" => $login,
"password" => $password,
"id" => array (
    "type" => "MSISDN",
    "value" => $msisdn
),
"productCode" => $prod_code

);



function callAPI($apiURL, $requestParamList) {
$jsonResponse = "";
$responseParamList = array();
$JsonData =json_encode($requestParamList);
 $postData = 'JsonData='.urlencode($JsonData);
$ch = curl_init($apiURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
echo $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($postData),
   'Authorization: Bearer ytSxhvjSUfNEurD5M6SOJPm6XAfu'
    )
);  
echo $jsonResponse = curl_exec($ch);
$responseParamList = json_decode($jsonResponse,true);
return $responseParamList;
}


function oneshotpayment($requestParamList) {
return callAPI(TML_CHARGE_URL, $requestParamList);
}
function subscription_payment($requestParamList) {
    return callAPI(TML_CHARGE_URL2, $requestParamList);
}

echo subscription_payment($requestParamList);
?>
```

**The error response is like below:**

```
{
    "transactionId": "",
    "timestamp": "2017-08-13T17:28:24+06:30",
    "recipientMsisdn": "",
    "code": "500.023.003",
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Request input is malformed or invalid"
}
```

Comment: So, what do you want from us? We don't even know what API you use and where's the docs to it.

Comment: @u_mulder what didn't you understand?

Comment: I didn't understand what is your question.

Comment: @u_mulder i need to send a http request through a php so i used a method for this... Url is being called through some inputs in json... When i run this php i got error response  thats the problem im facing..now u got it?

Comment: @tanni have you tried my naswer?

Comment: I will try .. n let u know ....

Comment: Can you post the Postman request and Postman response. I think your request object has the wrong format.

Comment: now it worked! thanks to @B.Desai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your **callAPI** method.

1) You dont need to do `urlencode` after you have done `json_encode`

2) Remove unnecessory concatination of `'JsonData='.` in string.

change you method like below

```
function callAPI($apiURL, $requestParamList) {
$postData = "";
$responseParamList = array();
$postData =json_encode($requestParamList);
$ch = curl_init($apiURL);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
echo $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);   //get status code

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Content-Length: ' . strlen($postData),
   'Authorization: Bearer ytSxhvjSUfNEurD5M6SOJPm6XAfu'
    )
);  
echo $jsonResponse = curl_exec($ch);
$responseParamList = json_decode($jsonResponse,true);
return $responseParamList;
}
```